# android game loop sleep

Tags: android, sleep, game-loop

I am working on a mini game for Android. I am using this code for the game loop.

```
private RefreshHandler mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler();

class RefreshHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Panel.this.update();
        Panel.this.invalidate();
    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
        this.removeMessages(101);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(101), delayMillis);
    }
};

public void update() {
    if (mMode == RUNNING) {
        ball.update(NR_PIX);

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            bords[i].update(NR_PIX);
        }

        Panel.lastBordHeight -= NR_PIX;

        if (mYBrickOffset == 0)
            mYBrickOffset = mYBrick;

        mYBrickOffset -= NR_PIX; 

        mRedrawHandler.sleep(mMoveDelay);
    }
}
```

The RefreshHandler class is from the SnakeView class example.

The code works ok. I have a Activity for a New Game button. When I first enter the Activity it's works. But if I exit the game and enter again the speed it's faster, thing that I don't wont or understand. If I exit the game and enter again using the New Game button the speed is faster even more.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve the problem overriding onPause in Activity. Here is the new code:

```
class RefreshHandler extends Handler {
    Handler h = new Handler();
    Run run = new Run();

    class Run implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Panel.this.update();
            Panel.this.invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
        h.postDelayed(run, delayMillis);
    }

    public void sleepCanceled() {
        h.removeCallbacks(run);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The speed of update() being called is never the same. One loop may take 16 milliseconds and the next loop may only take 14 milliseconds and it will continue to vary over time.

You need to try get it to loop at a fixed rate, this will keep your game running ant a consistent speed.

Try reading this: http://obviam.net/index.php/the-android-game-loop/ and there is an interesting discussion here: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=21372.0

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll look into them. I manage to solve the problem overiding onPause and using postDelay. Here is my new RefreshHandler class.